# GC overhead limit exceeded while loading big file

Tags: java, graph, garbage-collection, bigdata

Hi I am writing a java program to load a 2G file into memory, the data is a graph in the format of:

```
node_number: edge_point_1 edge_point_2 ... edge_point_k
```

and I want to import it into memory as an adjacency list but I get the garbage collector exceed error.

I noticed that the file is load into memory but the problem is while making linked-list. Here is my code:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Integer n1 = line.indexOf(":"), n2;
    Integer k = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, n1));
    n1 = n1 + 2;
    lists[k] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    do {
        n2 = line.indexOf(" ", n1);
        if (n2 == -1)
            lists[k].add(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(n1, line.length())));
        else
            lists[k].add(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(n1, n2)));
        n1 = n2 + 1;
    } while (n2 != -1);
}
```

Does anybody have any idea what's wrong with my code? I am compiling with Netbeans latest build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simple consume too much memory. Reduce it and increase you memory limit.

#### Reduce memory

You're using `LinkedList<Integer>` which requires maybe 50 bytes per `int` instead of `10`. As the easy step, switch to `ArrayList<Integer>` to save half of it. As the harder step, use `int[]` and resize them yourself as needed.

#### Increase you memory limit

Start your JVM with

```
java -Xmx8G
```

when you have 8 GB of free memory.